# Why am I getting resource id 13 in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to run a query on getting the last 9 entries from the database, something simple I did in text, but trying to do it in a table form seems to mess it up. Here is my query code:

```
<?
$con = Omitted
    // create query
$query = "SELECT * FROM libvid ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 9";

// execute query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM libvid ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 9");

// see if any rows were returned
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // yes
    // print them one after another
    echo "<table border='0'>";
     echo "<tr>";
     $col=0;
     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $col++;
    print '
        <td width="170px" height="130px">
          <font size="-3"><strong>'. $row['title'].'</strong></font><br>
          <a href="#'.$row['title'].'"    onClick="javascript:loadwindow(\'popup.php?id=' .$row['id']. '\')">
            <img class="imgb" style="border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 30px; -moz-border-radius: 30px;-khtml-border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px;" src=http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/'.$row['emurl'].'/0.jpg width="162" height="110" />
          </a>
        </td>';
    if($col % 3 ==0) print '</tr><tr>';

        }  //end foreach $newarr
 print '</tr></table>';
}
?>
```

I am getting the resource id #13 error and will not display anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better debug your problem, you should add error handling.  Update your `mysql_query` call as follows to see what errors you are getting:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM libvid ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 9");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Apart from the error you are getting, another problem I see is your use of  [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), which returns a numerical array and you are accessing it associatively i.e. `$row['title']`.  Please see the linked documentation.

I think you want to use either [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) like follows where you have the while loop defined:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

When you read the linked documentation, please take a note of the warning message about deprecation of `mysql_` functions.  You should look into using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`.